# PHP array of arrays: problem to push item on inner array

Tags: php, arrays, push

I would like to append elements to an array that is part of another array. I add an element to $aA in this way:

```
$aA[] = array('label'=>"string1",'data'=>array());
```

By this the array will be extended by new element with the following context in json notation:

```
{ index:'string1',data:{}}
```

The array referred to by 'data' is initially empty.

A bit later I would like to append/push the elements 1,2,3 to the 'data' array in the last element of $aA. I have tried with this:

```
end($aA)['data'][]=1;
end($aA)['data'][]=2;
end($aA)['data'][]=3;
```

with the following expected content of the last element i $aA

```
{ index:'string1',data:{1,2,3}}
```

But this doesn't work. The array referred to by 'index' is still empty.

How should I do this to make it work?

Comment: Try `$aA[ count( $aA ) - 1 ]['data'][] = ...` instead of `end($aA)...`

Comment: @marekful Thanks, your proposal worked fine! Now I just wonder why end($aA) doesn't work....

Comment: `end()` returns a copy of the last element in the array. Changing that will not be reflected in the original array.

Comment: Thanks, I learn day by day. This was a nasty one....

Answer (score 1):

How about you use `array_push`?

```
array_push($aA['data'], 1);
```

[PHP: array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Well, see comments on my original post. The problem is not the push operation, but how I refer to the last item on the list. Probably nothing wrong with your proposal but it will not solve my problem.